# Laravel Socialite - handleProviderCallback() method not showing stored session

Tags: php, laravel, function, scope, laravel-socialite

I am trying to integrate Socialite in my Laravel project. I am trying to store a session in buyerSignup.blade.php file and then trying to get that session value in Socialite's handleProviderCallback() method. But it is not showing any value don't know why. Although the other method
redirectToProvider() showing the session value.

I need that session value in handleProviderCallback() method to process it and take actions based upon the value of session. Below is a actual of code that I am using.

Storing a session value in buyerSignup.blade.php

```
@php

\Session::put('buyerSignupFb','true');

@endphp
```

Trying to get the above stored value in LoginController's handleProviderCallback() method.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App\sellerData;
use App\buyerData;
use App\sellerDealCat;
use App\subCatData;
use App\Session;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Socialite;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

  use AuthenticatesUsers;

 protected $redirectTo = '/home';

 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        $this->middleware('guest:seller')->except('logout');
        $this->middleware('guest:buyer')->except('logout');

    }


public function redirectToProvider()

{

return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();


}

public function handleProviderCallback()
{

//cant get the value of the session defined in buyerSignup.blade.php
// echo doesn't work too

return \Session()->get('buyerSignupFb');


}

}
```

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong or how to make it work. TIA

Comment: `handleProviderCallback()` its a callback for provider)) where u need to exchange your auth code to token

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/socialite#routing

Comment: @BohdanPetrenko so I cant access any session value in that method?

Answer (score 0):

U doing all good, but not enought, first u set a redirect provider

```
public function redirectToProvider()

{
     return Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->redirect();
}
```

it's good, when user will give access to his token, u need to handle callback in `handleProviderCallback()`, where u need to exchange user `auth code` to `acces token`. All of this socialite makes automatically, all what u need its just call it

```
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $externalUser = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->user();

\\check if user exists, if not create

    $auth->login($user, true);

    if ($user->type = 'seller'){$this->redirectTo = '/forSellers'} else {$this->redirectTo = '/forOtherGroup'}

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Comment: I got it, but I have two types of users sellers and buyers and I need to make login based upon the user. For that I am trying to access a session created in each page, SellerSignup and BuyerSignup views. After that I am trying to access that session value in handleProviderCallback(). So I can take actions based on the session value.

Comment: u got a user, find his profile by email, and check his type, if type seller make `return redirect(/forSellers)`, other `return redirect(/forOthers)`

Comment: after `$auth->login($user, true);` try to get session info

Comment: Why cant I access the session value in this method? It would be easier if I get the session value

Comment: u can, why not? but how u can get session info, if user is not login? First u need to make login, and after u can see all user session `$auth->login($user, true);  dd(Session::all());`

Comment: I am trying to get the session value from BuyerSignup.blade.php where session with name "BuyerSignupFb" has been created. User will first go to buyerSignup page and after clicking "sign up with fb" it will move to socialite method. Means when user will go to socialite methods the session (BuyerSignupFb) has been created already. But I am not able to get that session value in handleProviderCallback() method.

Comment: try to use php sessions, https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.session.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210651/discussion-between-bohdan-petrenko-and-faisal-shani).